# OnSelect Formula Switch to Other Screens Not Working

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

Pretty sure this belongs to the Power Apps forum but I'm gonna try my luck here as well:

I have been encountering a simple issue about switching screens depending on the value of the dropdown data card I have. This is the current formula I have:

```
Switch(
IssueRequestType_Dropdown.Selected,
"Other", Navigate(GenericFormScreen, ScreenTransition.None),
"Manual Commission Adjustment Request", Navigate(CommissionAdjustmentFormScreen, ScreenTransition.None),
"Miscellaneous Adjustment Request", Navigate(MiscellaneousAdjustmentFormScreen, ScreenTransition.None),
"Write-Off Request", Navigate(WriteOffFormScreen, ScreenTransition.None),
Navigate(MainScreen, ScreenTransition.None)
)
```

My error keeps saying 'Invalid argument type (Text). Expecting a Record value instead'. Can someone please explain this?

All form screens are present in case that's relevant to my question. Thank you.

Comment: Try using `IssueRequestType_Dropdown.Selected.Value` instead of `IssueRequestType_Dropdown.Selected.Value`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a drop down control in Power Apps, try using formula like below:

```
Switch(
    IssueRequestType_Dropdown.Selected.Value,
    "Other",
    Navigate(GenericFormScreen, ScreenTransition.None),
    "Manual Commission Adjustment Request",
    Navigate(CommissionAdjustmentFormScreen, ScreenTransition.None),
    "Miscellaneous Adjustment Request",
    Navigate(MiscellaneousAdjustmentFormScreen, ScreenTransition.None),
    "Write-Off Request",
    Navigate(WriteOffFormScreen, ScreenTransition.None),
    Navigate(MainScreen, ScreenTransition.None)
)
```

I have changed `IssueRequestType_Dropdown.Selected` to `IssueRequestType_Dropdown.Selected.Value` in formula.

**Documentation**: [If and Switch functions in Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-if)

Comment: Hi Ganesh,

Thanks for the suggestion. I actually ended up using the IssueRequestType_Dropdown.Selected.ColumName which worked.

Comment: Glad it is working for you now. Last part in formula is dependent on which control you are using (drop down or combo box) and the "items" property of the control. I am happy my suggestion helped you to get it working.

Comment: Hi @badsalvarado, can you please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept my above response as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list. Thank you!